# Deactivate accelerometer

Tags: hardware

I am having some trouble using games that use joysticks because my laptop has an accelerometer (I don't have the slightest idea why this might be useful on a laptop), and it's interfeering with joysticks. Linux finds it in /dev/input/js0

I would like to know how to disable/enable this so games or other things don't detect it.

Thank you very much.

This is the information in `/proc/bus/input/devices`

```
I: Bus=0019 Vendor=0000 Product=0000 Version=0000
N: Name="ST LIS3LV02DL Accelerometer"
P: Phys=lis3lv02d/input0
S: Sysfs=/devices/platform/lis3lv02d/input/input11
U: Uniq=
H: Handlers=event10 js0 
B: PROP=0
B: EV=9
B: ABS=7
```

Comment: The accelerometer detects when you drop your laptop, and quickly stops the HDD to minimize damage. That probably doesn't work on Linux. See [here](http://superuser.com/questions/149407/why-does-my-hp-pavilion-notebook-have-an-accelerometer).

Comment: Ok, that seems like a good use xD. I again doubt that works on Linux. I just want to disable it.

Answer (score 17):

A better solution is to unload **hp_accel module**: `sudo modprobe -r hp_accel`

If you don't want your system to load the module at every boot, simply blacklist it adding the following line to **/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf**:

**blacklist hp_accel**

Comment: This will disable the HDD protection which I would not do unless I have an SSD

Comment: @SuiciDoga I believe this accelerometer HDD protection is handled by some sort of firmware (maybe in bios) because it should be real-time and quick enough to turn off the HDD, so I think it's safe to disable it in OS.

Comment: This does the magic! Since i installed a SSD, this feature isn't required for now. Let gonna see if can increase battery save also =).

Answer (score 3):

[Answered by OP in question:](https://askubuntu.com/revisions/585706/3)

> Solved it `chmod -r /dev/input/js0` was enough

Comment: This doesn't seem to work on 20.04. the sensors still sending values.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a small program to read the Joystick under termilnal.
As you said I see it as a joystick on my laptop:
ST LIS3LV02DL Accelerometer
but when I plug in a real joystick it disappears from the list... and the real joystick is listed.