# ubuntu 19.10 64 bit upside down initial display

Tags: display, orientation

Total newbie loaded ubuntu 19.10 via DVD. First desktop display (GUI) was upside down and cursor also inverted.
Older HP laptop used but difficult to enter ANY commands with display inverted.
Years ago, I had some experience with UNIX but have forgotten most of what I knew. Retired programmer and software tester.

System is an HP dv6 laptop ser #CNF0195YW6. Display is NOT detachable. Memory is, I believe, maxxed  out at  about 4 gigs.
I have checked the DISPLAY settings and the only item there is RESOLUTION. 
This may be because this laptop may not allow rotation.
My next action will be to check the BIOS (which I am not terribly familiar with) to see if there is a setting for display orientation. By the way, using the ubuntu 'welcome screen' with its current upside down orientation is not easy. 
Checked BIOS : Insyde F29, v 3.5; product ID WQ685UA#ABA; system board 143F
BIOS (as currently loaded) doesn't seem to have any items related to orientation of the display.
Seems similar to a reported problem with 18.04

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/a/1034874/925971 - you could try this using terminal

Comment: Please find the serial number sticker. On that is also the Model Part Number. Please copy that, click [edit] and add that vital information to your question so all the facts we need are in the question. Other 'model' numbers elsewhere are marketing labels and not helpful in finding detail about your system. Please also run _`lsb_release -a && uname -a && lshw -c video | grep configuration`_ and add it into your question as well. Please don't use Add Comment, since that's our channel to you. All facts about your system should go in the Question with [edit]

Comment: In the `Displays` setting panel, is there a **rotation** or **orientation** setting? Any display settings in the BIOS?

Comment: Tell me the EXACT make/model #, and the output of `sudo dmidecode -s bios-version`.

Answer (score 0):

After poking around on the net, I found the same problem with 18.04 and a suggested answer. The suggestion (**xrandr -o normal** fixed the problem and the display is now normal.